# Can not converting properly in pdf to text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i want to do convert pdf to text format and using itextsharp dll for this here is my code which convert my pdf to string format but in some cases of pdf this code is not working proper converting like when i pass PDF file and suppose in pdf header there is  name like Microsoft windows then it converting  it like MMMiicccrrossofft WWiiiindooowsss and suppose there is email id like xyx@gmail.com than it giveing result like xxxyyyzzzz@@@ggggmaillll.com. can any one tell me why this happen in some case.

```
public static string ReadPDFFile(string pdfFile)
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        if (File.Exists(pdfFile))
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
                string currenttext = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfreader, i, strategy);
                currenttext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currenttext)));                
                text.Append(currenttext);
            }
            try
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        return Convert.ToString(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i pass PDF file and suppose in pdf header there is name like Microsoft windows then it converting it like MMMiicccrrossofft WWiiiindooowsss and suppose there is email id like xyx@gmail.com than it giveing result like xxxyyyzzzz@@@ggggmaillll.com. can any one tell me why this happen in some case.

You mention that that issue occurs especially with special text parts like headings or email addresses. I assume that those text parts are printed somewhat bold.

The reason why letters in such bold parts are extracted multiple times is that inside the PDF there most likely *are* multiple copies of those letters! To achieve the bold effect without actually using a bold font, some programs print the same character multiple times with a small displacement. This often is called "poor man's bold".

Other effects, e.g. some shadow, might use the same basic technique merely using a different color and possibly slightly larger displacements between the copies of the same character.

To extract such multiple copies of the same character as a single one, you have to create an extended text extraction strategy which recognizes these techniques. You can create them based on the code of the existing strategies `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` and `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` by checking whether there are multiple occurances of the same character at nearly the same coordinates.

Comment: thanks mkl, y right but i malso not getting email address which in hyperlink form

Comment: after using both this strategy i m not getting my hyperlink text

Comment: Interactive PDF features often get their appearance not from some page content but some *annotations* which are by default **not** processed by text extraction.